# Entity Framework IsRowVersion() without concurrency check

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, concurrency

We have a table that has a column called `Version` that is mapped as a SQL `rowversion`. This is done because we have an external system that maps to our data that relies on this column changing every time the table is updated. Originally we wanted this to be handled by SQL, but now we are finding we have Optimistic Concurrency exceptions. While these exceptions are there to safeguard data getting overwritten, for our case we do not care about this. We simply want the `timestamp` to continue incrementing, without Entity Framework checking it for concurrency issues.

Is there any way to do this?

Mapping:

```
Property(t => t.Version).IsRowVersion();
```

Comment: Yes, just remove it from your mapping. Sql Server will increment it on each update anyway.

Comment: I tried removing it from my mapping but i get an error: `cannot update timestamp column`

Comment: Did you actively mark the property as ignored? On second thoughts, why not remove it from your class model altogether?

Comment: We need to be able to use the column in our app as we need to provide the value to another app that uses our api, so removing it from the model is out of the question. The answer below has resolved our problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default EF implies row version type to be a optimistic concurrency token (included in the optimistic concurrency checks).

You can override that behavior by using the `IsConcurrencyToken` fluent API:

```
Property(t => t.Version).IsRowVersion().IsConcurrencyToken(false);
```

Comment: I'm going to test this now, if this works I could kiss you

Comment: works! thank you so much! we've been trying to find the source of these concurrency issues for months

Answer (score 0):

In EF core adding `IsConcurrencyToken(false)` will change the column type from `rowversion` to `varbinary(max)`.

Instead you should replace `IsRowVersion()` with `HasColumnType("rowversion")` like this:

```
Property(e => e.LastUpdatedRowVer).HasColumnType("rowversion").ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate();
```