# Entity Framework generic entity inheritance id error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance, entity-framework-core

Part 2 problem, which continues from here:
[EntityFramework Core - Update record fails with DbUpdateConcurrencyException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44313258/entityframework-core-update-record-fails-with-dbupdateconcurrencyexception)

Error:

> The derived type 'BinaryFile' cannot have KeyAttribute on property 'Id' since primary key can only be declared on the root type.

I am trying to make inheritance for my entities as much as possible, so I remove duplication as much as possible.

My inheritance structure:

```
public interface IEntityMinimum
{
    bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    byte[] Version { get; set; }
    string CreatedBy { get; set; }
}

public class EntityMinimum : IEntityMinimum
{
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] Version { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
}

public interface IEntity : IEntityMinimum
{
    object Id { get; set; }
    DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    DateTime? ModifiedDate { get; set; }
    string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
}

public interface IEntity<T> : IEntity
{
    new T Id { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Entity<T> : EntityMinimum, IEntity<T> 
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public T Id { get; set; }

    object IEntity.Id
    {
        get => Id;
        set => throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private DateTime? _createdDate;
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime CreatedDate
    {
        get => _createdDate ?? DateTime.UtcNow;
        set => _createdDate = value;
    }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime? ModifiedDate { get; set; }

    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
}

public class EntityMaximum : Entity<int>
{
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}

public class BinaryFile : EntityMaximum
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string UniqueName { get; set; }
    public Guid UniqueId { get; set; }
    public byte[] Content { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Campaign> Campaigns { get; set; }
}
```

I get this error when I use Fluent API to disable `isConcurrencyToken` on the `Version` field for the `EntityMinimum` class like this:

```
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44009020/entity-framework-isrowversion-without-concurrency-check
    builder.Entity<EntityMinimum>().Property(x => x.Version).IsRowVersion().IsConcurrencyToken(false);
```

This is required because I had another issue if I do not disable `isConcurrencyToken` on the `Version` field:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded.

If I remove fluent api configuration, it works, but doesn't update because of `Version` field which has `[TimeStamp]` attribute.

I have this `[TimeStamp]` `Version` field in `EntityMinimum` to append `Version` to every table, so I can use `TimeStamp` for synchronisation purposes between mobile and web data.

Am I doing this structure correctly, or should I get rid of `[TimeStamp] byte[] Version` and just use string `Version` and save `DateTime` ticks into it for synchronisation purpose?

Comment: what please show usage. i.e. `Product: Entity<Product>` ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the call

```
builder.Entity<EntityMinimum>()
```

marks the `EntityMinimum` class as *entity* (part of the EF Core inheritance strategy), while as I understand, you use the base class hierarchy just for implementation purposes.

Instead, you could use the EF Core model metadata services to turn off `IsConcurrencyToken` for the `Version` property of any real entity derived from `EntityMinimum` like  this:

```
foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
{
    if (typeof(EntityMinimum).IsAssignableFrom(entityType.ClrType))
        entityType.FindProperty("Version").IsConcurrencyToken = false;
}
```